# broadcast receiver like component in iOS for detecting change in internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I want to get notified whenever my iOS device is connected/disconnected to internet through my app. This is possible in android by using broadcast receiver. Is there any broadcast receiver like component in iOS through which I get notification for detecting change in internet connection?

I have searched through internet a lot but did not get any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Reachability API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). You might want to run this as a silent background thread and alert once there is a change in network connectivity.

Comment: Yes I want it to be run as silent background thread. Can you please tell me How can I use that as a silent background thread?

Comment: Please go through the API. Once registered, Reachability notifies you when there is a change in network.